# Navigating the Entity Framework Migration Options

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out the best way of migrating my database in my production environment, and I think that I am getting some of the terminology confused.

I have a class called "Migration" which I use to seed my database.  It's constructor looks like this (my DbContext is called SiteDatabase):

```
internal sealed class Migration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SiteDatabase>
{
    public Migration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

1. What does the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled do here?  Is this how I enabled Automatic Migrations?

In my 'Application_Start()' method, I have seen the following items added:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    new DbMigrator(new Migration()).Update();

    // Option 1
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SiteDatabase, Migration>());

    // Option 2
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SiteDatabase>());
}
```

2. Are these the only options available?
3. How does this relate to the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled that in the Migration class?

In the Package Manager Console, I know about the following commands:

```
> update-database
> add-migration
```

4. How does update-database relate to AutomaticMigrationsEnabled?  Is it still required?  What about when you create a new DbMigrator?
5. If I create migrations using add-migration, what is a good method for naming them?  I know that they are automatically named with a timestamp, but it also required an additional string to append to it.
6. Is there a way of controlling how the files generated with add-migration are named?

Comment: I don't have insight into the inner workings of Entity Framework and don't have the time to step through the code, but apparently Max Vasilyev has. This post might help you http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/

Answer (score 2):

> What does the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled do here? Is this how I enabled Automatic Migrations?

Evidently: yes. The effect from this is that you don't have to execute `add-migration` before calling `update-database`: it will generate a migration for you with just a timestamp for name. You won't be able to find this migration in the Migrations folder.

> Are these the only options available?

No, [there are more](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) like `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`, `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` and custom ones you create yourself.

> How does this relate to the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled that in the Migration class?

Automatic migrations just makes the migration process of your tables easier by making sure you don't have to execute it yourself anymore. The database initializer decides what to do about the database itself. They're distinct aspects but are connected in the way that they both work on your database.

> How does update-database relate to AutomaticMigrationsEnabled? Is it still required? What about when you create a new DbMigrator?

See above: you basically don't have to call `add-migration` anymore.

> If I create migrations using add-migration, what is a good method for naming them?

I'm not aware of any guidelines but I just summarize the content of the change. For example "add usermodel address" to add an address field to my user. This is really up to you to decide what works best.

> Is there a way of controlling how the files generated with add-migration are named?

I am not aware of such an option.